# Get value from URL after the last /

Tags: php, url

I have looked around for this but can only find links and references to this been done after an anchor hashtag but I need to get the value of the URL after the last / sign.

I have seen this used like this:

www.somesite.com/archive/some-post-or-article/53272

the last bit `53272` is a reference to an affiliate ID..

Thanks in advance folks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPs parse_url (which extracts the path from the URL) combined with basename (which returns the last part) will solve this:

```
var_dump(basename(parse_url('http://www.somesite.com/archive/some-post-or-article/53272',  PHP_URL_PATH)));
string(5) "53272"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
$url = 'www.somesite.com/archive/some-post-or-article/53272';
$id = substr(url, strrpos(url, '/') + 1);
```

Comment: +1 , for being the most eficient among all solutions posted (including  mine).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line with explode() and array_pop() :

```
$url = 'www.somesite.com/archive/some-post-or-article/53272';
echo array_pop(explode('/',$url)); //echoes 53272
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$url = "www.somesite.com/archive/some-post-or-article/53272";

$last = end(explode("/",$url));

echo $last;

?>
```

Use this.

Comment: That works perfect. There is however one problem not. When i go to the url 'www.somesite.com/archive/some-post-or-article/5327' I get a url not found. because i have added the /53272 on it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in PHP, but I would go for using the split function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php

Use it to split a String representation of your URL with the '/' pattern, and it will return you an array of strings. You will be looking for the last element in the array.

Comment: More than one way to skin a cat :)

Comment: Split is deprecated, you should use explode() instead. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: I'm commenting on my own answer to point out that split seems to be deprecated. You'd want to use explode instead, as one of the other answers suggests: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

This will work!

> ```
> $url = 'www.somesite.com/archive/some-post-or-article/53272';
>
> $pieces = explode("/", $url);
>
> $id = $pieces[count($pieces)]; //or $id = $pieces[count($pieces) - 1];
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you always have the id on the same place, and the actual link looks something like

http://www.somesite.com/archive/article-post-id/74355

```
$link = "http://www.somesite.com/archive/article-post-id/74355";
$string = explode('article-post-id/', $link);

$string[1]; // This is your id of the article :)
```

Hope it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$info = parse_url($yourUrl);
$result = '';

if( !empty($info['path']) )
{
  $result = end(explode('/', $info['path']));
}

return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'www.somesite.com/archive/some-post-or-article/53272';
$parse = explode('/',$url);
$count = count($parse);
$yourValue = $parse[$count-1];
```

That's all.