# how to get value from url after /

Tags: php

I have url like this www.example.com/user/1 and i want get user id which is 1. When i try it with my code i get right id but my css style is not applied to the page. But when i try to get id from url www.example.com?profile.php?user=1 i can see style of my page. The code what i use in first example is:

```
$request = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
     $path = $request["path"];
     $result = rtrim(str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $path), '/');
     $parts = $query = explode("/", $result);
     $user = $parts[2];
     $sql = "SELECT firstName, lastName FROM users WHERE id = ".$user." LIMIT 1";
     $res = $con->query($sql);
     $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
```

and where i try to get id for second example I use only $_GET method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get value from URL after the last /](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684224/get-value-from-url-after-the-last)

Comment: but i dont want to get value just from last / i want to get value after secound or third or some other /

Comment: The problem with the CSS not applied probably has to do with theURL and the way you call your CSS file. Use absolute path to the CSS,not relative, and you will be ok. Like www.example.com/css/your_css_file.css

Comment: @Yasen Zhelev  You were right tnx :)

Comment: Is your problem the CSS or how to get values between "/" actually? If it is the CSS only, I will edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: I'd wager your query has a SQL injection vulnerability in it - it looks very risky.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting my comment as answer.

The problem with the CSS not applied probably has to do with the URL and the way you call your CSS file. Use absolute path to the CSS,not relative, and you will be ok. Like www.example.com/css/your_css_file.css